# Remove matrix rows according to another matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm tring to remove the number of rows of a matrix to have same amount of rows as another matrix

for example:

```
a = [ 1 2
      3 4
      5 6 ]

b = [7 8]
```

What can I do to turn a into

```
a = [1 2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`size`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html):

```
a = a(1:size(b,1), 1:size(b,2));
```

`size(...,1)` is number of rows, and `size(...,2)` is number of columns. So this picks the right number of rows and of columns from `a`.